# How to crawl in url

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I want to scrape multiple urls

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false,userDataDir: "./user_data"});

   let elements = ['https://tr.pinterest.com/gamzeeerkek','https://tr.pinterest.com/jislaynekauany_']
   const result = await page.evaluate(() => {     

    for(let url of elements)
    {
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitFor(1000);
            let title = document.querySelector('.lH1').innerText;
            let title1 = document.getElementsByClassName('tBJ')[1].innerText; 

            data.push({title, title1});

    }
    return data; // Return our data array
    });

    browser.close();
    return result; // Return the data

};

scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // Success!
});
```

My **error** is :

> let page = await browser.newPage();
>                      ^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: callback for page.evaluate has to be async in case you want to use await inside it.

Comment: Hey @ozer, Did it help you? Or are you  still stuck?

Comment: @Yevhen i solved thx dude for answer

Comment: Cool! So accept the answer if that solved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see this error because you are using the `await` outside the `async`. Also, you have several mistakes and your script will not work even if you add the `async` keyword due to context and syntax errors.

Here is the script:

```
const scrape = async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false,userDataDir: "./user_data"});

const data = [];
const urls = ['https://tr.pinterest.com/gamzeeerkek','https://tr.pinterest.com/jislaynekauany_']
const page = await browser.newPage();

for (const url of urls) {
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.waitForSelector('.lH1');

  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const title = document.querySelector('.lH1').innerText;
    const title1 = document.getElementsByClassName('tBJ')[1].innerText; 

    return {title, title1};
  });

  data.push(result)
}
 await browser.close();

 return data; // Return the data
};

scrape().then((value) => {
 console.log(value); // Success!
});
```

Output:

> [ { title: 'Gamze Erkek', title1: 'Follow' },
>     { title: 'Jislayne', title1: 'Follow' } ]